# How to set Fn+F2 to show battery's status throug OSD and not power statistics?

Tags: 11.10, battery, shortcut-keys

In natty pressing <kbd>Fn</kbd>+<kbd>F2</kbd> on my Samsung NC10 opened a new notification with the remaining battery power. After upgrading to Oneiric, it opens the power statistics. Is the a way to revert this change?

Checking the battery status with the notification is much faster than finding it from the power statistics. I know that the remaining battery time can be set to be shown on the panel but I'm used to <kbd>Fn</kbd>+<kbd>F2</kbd>.

Comment: This question appears to be abandoned, if you are experiencing a similar issue please [ask a new question](http://askubuntu.com/questions/ask) with details pertaining to your problem. If you feel this question is *not* abandoned, please flag the question explaining that. I am flagging this for closure. Regards,

Answer (score 1):

Gnome has dropped this feature in Gnome 3.2 but seems to be willing to add a small OSD notification back. Please see https://bugs.launchpad.net/bugs/884038 for more details.